# ObjC protocol Implementation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

Ok here is the big problem. I had a library written in ObjC([this](http://stockchartview.org/)). There we had a defined protocol. When I tried to use it in swift file I get constantly:

> Type "XXX" does not conform to protocol "XXX"

To simplify things I made up a test project - it should be created as Swift project.

Then create ObjC header file(I called it StupidProtocol.h) with following protocol inside(please note each name and value to exactly match the given including uppercase/lowercase):

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>

- (NSString *)getAxisLabel:(id)axis Value:(CGFloat)value;

@end
```

In bridging header:

```
#import "StupidProtocol.h"
```

And then back in Swift file:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MyProtocol
{
    func getAxisLabel(axis: AnyObject!, value: CGFloat) -> String! {
        return ""
    }
}
```

And baam we got this error again even though auto-complete finishes the getAxisLabel function for me.

I strongly suspect that the problem is with argument "value" and it's function parameter "Value".

Any help will be highly appreciated.

EDIT

Please note that [this library](http://stockchartview.org/) is not technically mine, so I cannot change it. I need a way to use it in Swift without changing it's original declaration. My example is only to simplify my problem.

WHAT I TRIED

I have tried following scenarios with no success:

'has different arguments name from those required by protocol' error

```
func getAxisLabel(axis: AnyObject!, Value value: CGFloat) -> String! {
    return ""
}
```

'has different arguments name from those required by protocol' error

```
func getAxisLabel(axis: AnyObject!, Value: CGFloat) -> String! {
    return ""
}
```

'type does not conform to protocol'

```
func getAxisLabel(axis: AnyObject!, Value: CGFloat) -> NSString! {
    return ""
}
```

SOLUTION

See [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31110293/1472337)

Comment: Obj c is uppercase V and swift is lowercase v. Make them both lowercase. It should be lowercase in both.

Comment: try writing the swift method with external param name "Value" and internal param name of "value" like: "Value value: CGFloat"

Comment: That might fix the problem but you shouldn't have the uppercase V in the first place. Drop it and it will work.

Comment: Please note that this method declaration is not mine - I totally agree it's declared wrong. But I need to use the library that has this declaration in Swift. If you could help me somehow with this it'll be great.

Comment: Then @hola fix of Value value: CGfloat should work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if this is a bug or not. The Objective-C protocol method

```
- (NSString *)getAxisLabel:(id)axis Value:(CGFloat)value;
```

(with uppercase "V" in `Value:`) is mapped to Swift as

```
func getAxisLabel(axis: AnyObject!, value: CGFloat) -> String!
```

(with lowercase "v" in `value:`), but none of

```
func getAxisLabel(axis: AnyObject!, value: CGFloat) -> String! { }
func getAxisLabel(axis: AnyObject!, Value: CGFloat) -> String! { }
```

is accepted by the compiler to satisfy the protocol requirement.

As a workaround, you can annotate the method with an explicit
Objective-C selector name:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MyProtocol
{
    @objc(getAxisLabel:Value:)
    func getAxisLabel(axis: AnyObject!, value: CGFloat) -> String! {
        return ""
    }
}
```

Comment: You are a life saver! I knew it should be something with @objc keyword as a workaround but didn't know how to exactly use it. Great to know for future references also!